# defcustom not appearing in Customize UI

Tags: customize, autoload, require, load

I have a problem that variables defined with `defcustom` in elisp files under `~/.elisp` do  not appear in the Customize UI.

In particular, I use word-count-mode from https://github.com/tomaszskutnik/word-count-mode/blob/master/word-count.el.
Since it contains

```
(defcustom word-count-word-regexp "[a-z0-9_-]+"
  "Regexp what is counted as words.")
```

I would have thought that I should then be able to do `M-x customize-apropos word-count-word-regexp`, for example, and be able to customize this variable. But nothing appears as "word-" at all.

The manual at https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Variable-Definitions.html seems to indicate that they should?

Comment: `~/.elisp` is an unusual directory name.  Can you please confirm that you've actually added that to your `load-path` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just because something is defined in an Elisp file, that doesn't mean that that file ever gets *loaded*. And if it doesn't get loaded then its contents are unknown to Emacs.

To use `M-x customize-option` to customize an option, *you must load the file* that contains the `defcustom` that defines that option.

To load a file, put it in your `load-path`, then `require` it in your init file. Putting it in your `load-path` means adding its directory to the value of variable `load-path`, which you can do with `add-to-list.

For example, this will make all files in directory `~/.elisp` (but not in subdirectories) loadable using `require`:

```lisp
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.elisp")
```

If the `defcustom` is autoloaded (it has an autoload cookie (`;;;###autoload` or other autoload declaration), and if an autoloads file that has been generated to include it has been loaded, then you don't need to explicitly load the file with the `defcustom` - it will be loaded automatically. But that doesn't seem to be the case for your `defcustom.

Comment: Thanks -- `require` was the key here! I had the package loaded with `autoload`, which means it is not actually loaded at startup. See also https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/364/when-should-i-use-autoload-instead-of-require